# Altova's and Cooktop's different result

Tags: xslt

I have lookup table from this table we take result if buyeritemcode=substring(field[@id='0'], 11,3) then subfamily=subfamily from lookup table, otherwise '9':

```
<lookup>
    <Code>
        <BuyerItemCode>439</BuyerItemCode>
        <Subfamily>016</Subfamily>          
    </Code>
</lookup>
```

Xml file looks:

```
<document>
    <line id="14">
        <field id="0"><![CDATA[MMM4443 419280600000]]></field>
    </line>
    <line id="15">
        <field id="0"><![CDATA[MMM4443 414390600000]]></field>
    </line>
</document>
```

I need to compare this data with lookup.xml and if data not compare insert constant 9. With altova v11 my program works, with cooktop doesn't, I mean comparing is false.
My program looks:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="date exsl">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="ProdSubfamily" match="Subfamily" use="../BuyerItemCode"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Interchange>
            <Group>
                <Message>
                    <xsl:if test="/document/line[(substring(field[@id='0'], 1,3)='MMM')]">
                        <xsl:apply-templates mode="MMM" select="/document"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </Message>
            </Group>
        </Interchange>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template mode="MMM" match="/document">
        <PriceCatalogue-Lines>
            <xsl:for-each select="/document/line[contains(substring(field[@id='0'], 1,3),'MMM') and not(contains(substring(field[@id='0'],9,1),'0'))]">
                <xsl:variable name="inputProd" select="substring(field[@id='0'], 11,3)"/>
                <Line>
                    <Line-Item>
                        <LineNumber>
                            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                        </LineNumber>
                        <BuyerItemCode>
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring(field[@id='0'], 11,3)"/>
                        </BuyerItemCode>
                        <SubFamily>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="substring(field[@id='0'], 11,3) = document('lookup.xml')/*/*/BuyerItemCode">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="document('lookup.xml')">
                                        <xsl:for-each select="key('ProdSubfamily',$inputProd)">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="'9'"/>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </SubFamily>
                    </Line-Item>
                </Line>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </PriceCatalogue-Lines>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Correct result which I get with Altova and I want to will get this result with cooktop:

```
<Interchange>
    <Group>
        <Message>
            <PriceCatalogue-Lines>
                <Line>
                    <Line-Item>
                        <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
                        <BuyerItemCode>928</BuyerItemCode>
                        <SubFamily>9</SubFamily>
                    </Line-Item>
                </Line>
                <Line>
                    <Line-Item>
                        <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
                        <BuyerItemCode>439</BuyerItemCode>
                        <SubFamily>016</SubFamily>
                    </Line-Item>
                </Line>
            </PriceCatalogue-Lines>
        </Message>
    </Group>
</Interchange>
```

BAD result which I get with Cooktop:

```
<Interchange>
<Group>
<Message>
<PriceCatalogue-Lines>
<Line>
<Line-Item>
<LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
<BuyerItemCode>928</BuyerItemCode>
<SubFamily>9</SubFamily>
</Line-Item>
</Line>
<Line>
<Line-Item>
<LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
<BuyerItemCode>439</BuyerItemCode>
<SubFamily>9</SubFamily>
</Line-Item>
</Line>
</PriceCatalogue-Lines>
</Message>
</Group>
</Interchange>
```

Comment: What is the output from Cooktop? An empty `<Message>` element?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation of the problem and for an easy solution. :)

Comment: @LarsH: on cooktop Subfamily = 9.

Comment: @Petras: can you post the output from cooktop, to avoid our having to keeping asking for more detail? The Altova output also has a SubFamily with content `9`. I guess you're saying that in cooktop, it's `9` for *both* SubFamily elements?

Comment: @LarsH: I correct it, also add result from cooktop.

Comment: @Petras: I have found a mistake in the way I substituted the file URL into your code. When done correctly now, all 8 XSLT processors produce your wanted result. See the update to my answer and my hypothesis as to what is going wrong with the XSLT processor used by CookTop.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is in the source XML document**:

The CDATA sections contain an unnecessary `[` character and it is the first character of the text node. This means that:

```
substring(field[@id='0'], 1,3)='MMM'
```

is always `false()`

**Solution**:

**Replace**:

```
<field id="0"><![CDATA[[MMM4443 419280600000]]></field>
```

**with**:

```
<field id="0"><![CDATA[MMM4443 419280600000]]></field>
```

**Also replace**:

```
<field id="0"><![CDATA[[MMM4443 414390600000]]></field>
```

**with**

```
<field id="0"><![CDATA[MMM4443 414390600000]]></field>
```

**Now, regardless of the XSLT processor used (I have 9 of them at home and could run this on 8 of them: MSXML3/4, .NET XslCompiledTransform and XslTransform, AltovaXML, Saxon 6.5.4, Saxon 9.1.05 and XQSharp), the result of the transformation is what I guess you wanted**:

```
<Interchange>
  <Group>
    <Message>
      <PriceCatalogue-Lines>
        <Line>
          <Line-Item>
            <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
            <BuyerItemCode>928</BuyerItemCode>
            <SubFamily>9</SubFamily>
          </Line-Item>
        </Line>
        <Line>
          <Line-Item>
            <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
            <BuyerItemCode>439</BuyerItemCode>
            <SubFamily>016</SubFamily>
          </Line-Item>
        </Line>
      </PriceCatalogue-Lines>
    </Message>
  </Group>
</Interchange>
```

**My guess is that Cooktop's XSLT processor needs some configuration in order to be enabled to execute the `document()` function** -- study the available documentation how to do this.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: xml file I repair, I mean I did mistake when writing document's lines here, add more "[" if it needed. Program still not working. in your answer I saw incorrect result. In the second Line where BuyerItemCode=439, subfamily should be taken from lookup table and equal 016 now is equal 9. with cooktop I also got this result..

Comment: @Petras: You must edit your question and define what do you mean by "not working" -- what is the result you are getting and what is the result you want produced.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: I edit question, also add cooktop result that is wrong.

Comment: @Dimitre, I see that the output you posted has the same problem as the OP got from Cooktop - 9 instead of 016, for the second `<Subfamily>`. Do any of your 9 processors get the answer he wants?

Comment: @LarsH: would be able to check at home -- 6hrs from now. Please, do remind me.

Comment: @Petras and @LarsH: I had an error in substituting the file URL only in one place. Only now I saw that there are two occurences of the `document()` function in @Petras' code. When I substituted the file URL in both places I get the result that @Petras wants on 8 of the 9 XSLT processors I have. MSXML 6 gives an error, because it needs a special comannd-line option for allowing the document function.

Comment: @LarsH: @Alejandro is no longer a user of SO :(

Comment: @Dimitre: sorry to hear about @Alej. I will miss him.

Answer (score 0):

Petras, the output you're seeing could mean the XSLT processor is not able to find the lookup.xml file.

Since you're using a relative URL ('lookup.xml'), do you know what the base URL is? In other words, relative to what?

By default, I believe the base URL used is that of the stylesheet. If you pass a second argument to document(), you can explicitly set the base URL. E.g.:

```
document('lookup.xml', /)
```

would look for 'lookup.xml' relative to the input XML file.

You could fix the problem, or at least find out if that *is* the problem, by providing an absolute URL to 'lookup.xml'. Why don't you try that, and let us know if it worked. E.g.

```
document('/home/lars/lookup.xml')
```

or

```
document('file:///c:/temp/lookup.xml')
```

P.S. XML Cooktop has been a great piece of software, but it seems to be rather old and now apparently unmaintained. This becomes a problem when glitches appear. You might want to try other XSLT tools, like OxygenXML or StylusStudio, that are still maintained.

Comment: @LarsH: I'm trying to use addres link and other examples from yours post, but it's not working, the result was the same first and second subfamily=9. Also I try to change condition, I mean instead of '=' use '!=' (I mean: <xsl:when test="substring(field[@id='0'], 11,3) != document('file:///C:\Users\petrasr\Desktop\lookup.xml')/*/*/BuyerItemCode">) result was first subfamily= empty, the second=016. So I'm thinking that something wrong with condition when.

Comment: @LarsH: I showed in my question all my programs, data which I use and two different result on altova and cooktop. If I solve it, I show how I solve it and close this case.

Comment: @Petras, thanks for showing your absolute URL. You may need to **change backslashes to forward slashes**. That's why I asked you to show exactly what you tried... otherwise I would not have had a way to know that you used backslashes.

Comment: @Petras, it makes sense that if the `=` test returns false, then there is no matching BuyerItemCode in the lookup document, so if you try to use a non-existent match, the first Subfamily will be empty. In other words, your original `when` condition was correct. It works fine in Altova, right?

Comment: @LarsH: Yes it works fine in Altova, and I think in logic way it should be.

Comment: @Petras - ok. Please let me know what happens when you change backslashes to forward slashes in your absolute URL for lookup.xml.